# p odd prime. Prove that if $a\equiv b\pmod p$ then $a^p\equiv b^p\pmod p^2$. Then show $x^5+y^5=z^5$ has no integer solutions with $5\not\mid xyz$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

**Question:**
Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that if $a\equiv b \pmod p$ then $a^p\equiv b^p \pmod p^2$. Then show the Diophantine equation $x^5+y^5=z^5$ has no integer solutions with $5\not\mid xyz$.

**My working so far:** 
$a\equiv b \pmod p\Longrightarrow a=b+kp$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so 
 $$ a^p = (b+kp)^p = \sum_{i=0}^p {p\choose i}(kp)^i ~b^{p-i} = b^p + k~p^2~b^{p-1} +  \sum_{i=2}^p {p\choose i}(kp)^i ~b^{p-i} \equiv b^p\pmod{p^2}.$$

How can I use this to prove the latter statement?

Answer (score 2):

Write the Fermat equation of exponent $5$ in the form $x^5+y^5+z^5=0$.
We have $x^5\equiv x \mod 5$, $y^5\equiv y \mod 5$ and $z^5\equiv z \mod 5$, hence $x+y+z\equiv 0\mod 5$. Without loss of generality we may assume, because $5\nmid xyz$, that $x\equiv y\mod 5$, hence $x^5\equiv y^5 \mod 25$, and $−z^5 ≡ x^5 + y^5 ≡ 2 x^5 \mod 25$. However, the equation $x ≡ y \mod 5$ also implies that
$−z ≡ x + y ≡ 2 x \mod 5$ and $−z^5 ≡ 2^5 x^5 ≡ 32 x^5 \mod 25$. 
Combining the two results and dividing both sides by $x^5$ yields a contradiction
$2 ≡ 32 \mod 25$.

Comment: Shouldn't you get $x+y \equiv z \pmod{5}$ and not $x+y+z \equiv 0\pmod{25}$? Also, you can't really assume without loss of generality that $x \equiv y \pmod{5}$.

Comment: I meant, exponent $5$ for Fermat in the form  $x^5+y^5+z^5=0$. And yes, you can show that two of them must be equivalent modulo $5$. Check the possibilities $\pm 1,\pm 2$.

Comment: why do we have $x^5\equiv x ~(mod~5)$,$y^5\equiv y ~(mod~5)$ and $z^5\equiv z ~(mod~5)$ I also don't really understand how you know $x\equiv y ~(mod~5)$ or why $-z^5\equiv 25x^5 ~(mod~25)$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. It wasn't clear before that you were considering the equation in the form $x^5+y^5+z^5=0$. I assumed that you were working with the original equation $x^5+y^5=z^5$, since you did not say otherwise previously. My comment about not being able to assume WLOG that $x \equiv y \pmod{5}$ was also assuming that you were working with the original equation, so that's fine. I'll point out 2 typos though: It should be $x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ instead of $x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$ in your 2nd line. It should be $-z^5 \equiv 2^5x^5$ instead of $-z^5 \equiv 25x^5$.

Comment: @IvanLoh: thanks a lot.

Comment: @user141647: this is little Fermat: $x^p\equiv x \mod p$ for $p=5$.